# Porting an old installation to a fresh CiviCRM

Tags: upgrade, data-import, migration

We have a very old installation, it is totally upgraded, but has been around for more than 10 years and survived both major Civi-upgrades and server migrations.

I'm starting to feel that all the upgrades is starting to take its toll. E.g. when I ask about some things it is evident that the current default is different than what it was when we started. And that makes for some misunderstandings and errors. I tried to change the Resource URLs to using URL-variables as per recommendation and almost lost the whole installation... This just feels fragile.

Is there a way, probably not simple, but perhaps straight forward, that we could get all data from our current installation into a shiny, new and freshly installed CiviCRM?

Much of the configuration is in the database, such as the Resource URLs, which obviously forces some manual work. But I'm still interested in suggestions, even on a principal level, if only to understand what  work would be involved.

Answer (score 3):

I have a few installs that are around 10 years since they started and I've run into a few problems similar to those you describe.  But the problems were all fixable and those installs are still working & being upgraded just fine. My take on it would be do things like change resource urls as you mention (I did this too), have backups & battle through.  I don't know of any easy way of unloading & reloading the system, the idea is appealing but almost certainly not worth the hassle IMHO.

Comment: Also compare your civicrm.settings.php file with one from a fresh installation. Adapt your settings file so it has the same structure as a new civicrm.settings.php file.